# How can we take price (sum) of repeated day but id also needed in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to plot graph using chart.js. In x-axis I need to show `day`. In left y-axis I need to show `price`, In right y-axis I need to show `id`. At-present my problem is repeated day in x-axis. Please check below mentioned query and result.

**Query**

```
SELECT od.id, sum(op.price), od.status, DATE_FORMAT(od.created_at, '%d %m') AS day 
FROM order_positions op 
INNER JOIN orders od ON od.id = op.order_id 
WHERE od.status = 'finished' 
GROUP BY op.order_id 
ORDER BY od.created_at LIMIT 20
```

**Data** This is the result I am getting

```
id  sum(op.price)   status      day     
7   180.00         finished     09 06
17  70.00          finished     09 06
19  48.00          finished     09 06
20  20.00          finished     13 06
21  31.00          finished     13 06
22  20.00          finished     15 06
23  20.00          finished     15 06
```

**Tables are**

`order_positions`

```
id  order_id price 
  1    7       100
  2    7        80
  3    17       35
  4    17       35
```

`orders`

```
id    status     date
7    finished    09 06
17   finished    09 06
19   finished    09 06
20   finished    13 06
```

Comment: group by day required instead of group by id

Comment: show your table with data and your desired output

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I have added tables also

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to group it by the `od.created_at` instead of `op.order_ID`

```
SELECT od.id, 
   Sum(op.price), 
   od.status, 
   Date_format(od.created_at, '%d %m') AS day 
FROM   order_positions op 
   INNER JOIN orders od 
           ON od.id = op.order_id 
WHERE  od.status = 'finished' 
GROUP  BY od.created_at 
ORDER  BY od.created_at 
LIMIT  20
```

Comment: I have added tables also. I applied this query but I lose id. Eg. On 09 06 two two order placed and id is 7 and 17. If we group it with created_at order id will loose

Comment: @sam sam You should be fine then if youare grouping it by the od.created_at and the od.id